# Can the value attribute of a textbox input be null?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following code:

```
function validateForm () {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```

Is it necessary to check if `x == null` to correctly validate if the form is filled?

Can the text-box input value ever be *null*?

Comment: it can not be null so the check is useless

Comment: @epascarello, I agree that _"The value of a field can not be null, it's always a string value"_ but what could be reason of testing `null` as it is been observed in many _snippets_.. Something related to legacy browsers or something ?

Comment: I have been saying it for 10+ years it is a useless check and people still do it.

Comment: People do it for the same reason they put the `javascript:` prefix in their inline event handlers like `onclick="javascript:someFunction();"`.  That is to say that they're copying poor code without understanding it.

Comment: One theory I read is that the `type="number"` input can return `null` if the user specifes a non-number. Chrome doesn't even let me enter a non-number, and IE doesn't return `null`, but it could be an older or another browser. Also, I've read about DOM elements not yet being visible (if being dynamically loaded), but I don't see why `null` would appear in that case either (the element should be `null` and stop execution). Maybe older browsers.

Comment: input of `type="number"` value, will & should also return a string type, even when it signifies a number. There should be no type conversion at that domain. So, obviously any _input property value_ will have to be of a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a textbox: is, should, or can never be *null*.

Initially: every default \ empty value of a given *element* property value, should match the Type of its expected value. 
Even though, the types of JavaScript are somewhat generic, the default/empty type of element property values should comply to the accepting type of the assignable value.

```
typeof document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value
>> "string"
```

This is not an obvious requirement to every browser vendor out there, but it's a principle, no developer should oversee.

Any given *Event Property* of a *DOM Element* expects a *function*. The *type* of a *function* is *object*. A result of failed construction of any specific object, is the *null* object. That's why the *typeof* null, is *object*. An object which doesn't contain an object but preserves its semiotic type.

```
typeof document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].onclick
>> "object"
```

Therefore the meaning of a *null value*, is that it should have been some sort of an *object*. Which is: an object that doesn't contain an object. And that's null.

```
document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].onclick
>> null
```

Consequentially typeof *NaN*, should be *number*..., and so on.

An *input value* that expects a type of *string* should therefore, always be of a string type, a string that doesn't contain any string value, e.g.: "" - by default!

```
document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value
>> ""
```

Therefore your [not empty] conditional of the "Name must be filled out" requirement can simply be checked with:

```
function validateForm () {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if ( x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```

But since it's a "name" field, you might be needing some additional conditional precautions to make sure it validates only the tokens that comply to your acceptance.
A task which may very well become quite robust.
However, the `if ( x == "")` will suffice to make sure that it's not empty.

Congratulations to you who reached this line by reading.

**EDIT**

Current browsers also support a built-in **required** property on input elements.
To avoid the completely unreliable browser sniffing, browser version, etc, we can use feature detection in writing browser vendor unaware code.
The `required` property is the exact equivalent of `if ( x == "")`.

Here is a "demo" (!not to be confused with production code).

```js
 _ = document.all;

 "required" in _.nameField ? 
      _.nameField.required = 1 : "otherwise add your javascript routine to (_.nameF..) here";

 console.log(({
   "true": "property supported",
   "false": "unsupported property"
 })[!!_.nameField.required]);

 delete _;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="nameField">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you do the following:

```
function validateForm () {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if ( ! x ) {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That way it will check if x is empty string, null, undefined or NaN (x should always be a string).

I also advise to remove the alert from the validation function, and test the result of the function to display the alert.

Comment: Why test the type? It will always be a string.

Comment: Oh gosh you are right nnnnnn, the value property is always a string. Removed unnecessary code from answer.

Comment: `if ( x ) {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
`

This will alert you exactly the opposite i.e. when the name is really filled.

Comment: Thanks Bekim, that was so obvious that I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been said in both other answers and comments that in this particular case an input **value** attribute is never *null*. So no, it is not necessary to perform that check. Simply with the expression `(x == '')` or even `(x)`, as pointed in other answers, would suffice in your particular case.

As a note, doing `(x == null || x == "")` would actually return **false** for all cases where `x` is either *empty*, *not defined* (or initialized I guess), *zero* or *false*, including arrays with zero elements or just one empty slot. That sounds as overkill, but given my *lack of knowledge about javascript*, it may be useful in a certain situation I do not know about. (Which then could have been copied at some point into the input.value validation we see in the question snippet)